# Best structure of Multiple indexed map

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, multimap

## Problem

Multiple indexed map :

- A value has several key, that can be used to find the value in a short time (may be less than O(n)).
- The key is NON-UNIQUE, which means `key1: val1`, `key1: val2`, `key1: val3` could be possible.
- When the value is removed, all equal values must be removed from the map.

## Example

### Structure of `Book` queue.

- A `Book` has multiple authors, and the `Authour`s can be searched in a short time.
- `Book` is concurrently added or removed in that Queue.
- `Author`s can write multiple `Book`s.

### Process

- Author is from input, then find anyone of the books in queue.
- The book is removed from the queue.

One I thought is the map can be simillar to multimap, but removing the key-value pairs from the map while iterating the authors of the book is unsuitable solution. When the author and books total count is about millions, the elapsing time can get greater.

Can anybody help me to decide the structure?

## UPDATE:

As @gdomo suggested(book-author, author-book map), I wrote code as follows:

```java
    public class Book {
        ...
        private List<String> authors;
    }

    Set<Book>> pendingBooks = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Set<Book>> cacheMapBooksByAuthor = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void processAuthorCheck(String author) {
        Set<Book> books = cacheMapBooksByAuthor.put(author, ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet());
        if (books == null)
            return;

        for (Book book : books) {
            pendingBooks.remove(book);          // REMOVE a BOOK from QUE

            this.processBook(book); // TODO

            List<String> authors = book.getAuthors();
            if (authors == null)
                continue;
            for (String author : authors) {
                Set<Book> tmpBooks = cacheMapBooksByAuthor.get(author).remove(book);        // remove THAT BOOK for all other authors
            }
        }
    }

    public static void pushBook(Book book) {
        List<String> authors = book.getAuthors();
        if (authors == null)
            return;

        for (String authors : authors) {
            Set<Book> books = cacheMapBooksByAuthor.get(authors);
            if (books == null) {
                Set<Book> oldBooks = cacheMapBooksByAuthor.putIfAbsent(authors, books = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet());
                if (oldBooks != null)
                    books = oldBooks;
            }
            books.add(book);
        }
    }
```

I used `Set` instead of `Queue` to avoid conflicts of book.

One I'm not satisfied with is release of book variable does't affect authors book variables, as i exprienced in C++. (Because of java object reference)

Is there any better solution over this structure?

Comment: Had a bit similar problem, finally came up a pair of map. In your case it could be multimaps book-authors and author-books. Corollary, we have to change them synchronously

Comment: All process must be thread safe, and book, author values must be removed from memory as they get unusable. This is the most difficult situation for me

Comment: Well, all the concurrency could be easily solved at least with simple synchronization. If you are looking for a lock-free (at least partially) solution, then its for sure more tough, but probably general synchronozation is ok

Comment: I hate lock based sync. It's about spring mvc proj, and lock free is the only way for me

Comment: I can hardly imagine 100% lock free solution. All that stuff would be anyway enclosed in some managing class, so for you just a typical method would be available. It doesn't matter is it Spring or not, any method of any library could be synchronized under the hood. For example, basic `someMap.put()` could turn out to `someMap` be got as `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>())`

Comment: I think it can be done lock free if eventual consistency is acceptable. In other words, if it’s OK for a book to be temporarily indexed under one author and not the other right as it is being added or removed. Is that OK?

Comment: By the way, why do you need the book to be in a queue? Would some other collection type (such as a set) also be ok? Is there something special about a book's position in a queue?

Comment: @k314159 a book is a type of attendance checking for the authors. and insertion rate of book is high. When processor get a book from queue, there is a something complicated routine must be processed

Comment: I think there’s not enough detail in the question to give an answer that will suit your needs